how to extract all urls included in a web application repository (relative and absolute urls)(url crawling)
I want to get all urls included in a webapp repository
It may use any framework (react, angular etc).
I tried to get all routes from router configuration files.
For example if a web app is react-based, The router file may look like
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import Team from './pages/Team';
import Company from './pages/Company';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />}>
        <Route path="team" element={<Team />} />
        <Route path="company" element={<Company />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);

export default App;

I want to extract the routes ('/','/about','/about/team','/about/comapny'). And is it good to use this approach to take all urls?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
